# Delaying a method based on page results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am retrieving results from NCBI's online Blast tool with 'net/http' and 'uri'. To do this I have to search through an html page to check if one of the lines is "Status=WAITING" or "Status=READY". When the Blast tool has finished the status will change to ready and results will be posted on the html page.

I have a working version to check the status and then retrieve the information that I need, but it is inefficient and is broken into two methods when I believe that there could be some way to put them into one.

```
def waitForBlast(rid)
    get = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?'), {:RID => "#{rid}", :CMD => 'Get'})
    get.body.each{|line| (waitForBlast(rid) if line.strip == "Status=WAITING") if line[/Status=/]}
end

def returnBlast(rid)
    blast_array = Array.new
    get = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?'), {:RID => "#{rid}", :CMD => 'Get'})
    get.body.each{|line| blast_array.push(line[/<a href=#\d+>/][/\d+/]) if line[/<a href=#\d+>/]}
    return blast_array
end
```

The first method checks the status and is my main concern because it is recursive. I believe(and correct me if I'm wrong) that designed as is takes too much computing power when all that I need is some way to recheck the results within the same method(adding in a time delay is a bonus). The second method is fine, but I would prefer if it was combined with the first somehow. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's difficult to say, but I suspect you could simplify your search quite a bit using an in-string search of the body. In addition, for anything but the most-trivial parsing tasks, a parser will save you much anguish over the long run. I recommend Nokogiri. Also, look at using Ruby's built-in `Open::URI`. It's much easier to use compared to `Net::HTTP` and `URI`.

Comment: Also, your `"#{rid}"` can be simplified to `rid` or `rid.to_s` if `rid` is not already a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/kwicher/ruby-blast-at-ncbi/blob/master/ncbi_blast.class.rb) implementation. This is what he does:

```
 res='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?CMD=Get&FORMAT_OBJECT=SearchInfo&RID=' + @rid
 while status = open(res).read.scan(/Status=(.*?)$/).to_s=='WAITING'
   @logger.debug("Status=WAITING")
   sleep(3)
 end
```

I think using the string scanner might be a bit more efficient than iterating over every line in the page, but I haven't looked at it's implementation so I may be wrong.

Comment: Could you explain the @logger.debug("Status=Waiting") to me. Im not familiar with it.

Comment: That just prints out `Status=WAITING` to the ruby console. See [this](http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/a/logger.htm).